# Generation of restricted increasing integer sequences

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I am looking for an effective way to generate a complete list of integer sequences

```
 {a_1,a_2,...,a_n}
```

of the length $n$ such that
$$0\le a_1\le a_2\le\dots\le a_n< m,$$

with two integer parameters $n$ and $m$.

I can imagine to perform this via

```
Table[Sort[IntegerDigits[x-1,m,n]],{x,m^n}]
```

and then delete duplicates, but surely there should exist a much more effective way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since we can map such sequence

$$0\leq a_1\leq a_2\leq a_3 \leq \cdots \leq a_{n-1}\leq a_n < m   $$
to
$$0 < b_1 = a_1+1 < b_2 = a_2+2 <  b_3 =a_3+3 <\cdots  < b_n=a_n+n < m+n  $$
and
$\{b_1,b_2,\cdots b_n\}$ is  the `n` subsets of `Range[m+n-1]`

And we can get $\{a_1,a_2,\cdots a_n\}$ from $\{b_1,b_2,\cdots b_n\}-\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$

```
m = 8;
n = 5;
list = Subsets[Range[m+n-1], {n}]
Subtract[#, Range[n]] & /@ list
```

Comment: nice!!!. You probably meant `With[{m = 10, n = 5}, 
 Subtract[1 + #, Range[n]] & /@ Subsets[Range[m + n - 1], {n}]]`? (+1)

Comment: @kglr Thanks! I make mistake.

Comment: That's really amazing! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

With a small trick, we can do this using the `Table` function. This is necessary because `Table` has the attribute HoldAll.

For a small example, we first set m and n:

```
m=4;
n=2;
```

We then create a list of variables and a list of iterators and join them into the body of `Table`:

```
var = Table[x[i], {i, n}];
iter = Table[{x[i], x[i - 1] + 1, m-1}, {i, n}] /. x[0] -> -1;
body = PrependTo[iter, var]
```

Finally we apply `Table` to the body and Flatten to get ride of superfluous braces:

```
Flatten[Table @@ body, 1]
```

This gives:

```
{{0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}}
```