# Is there a function to generate “subsets” allowing duplicates?

Tags: permutation, subset

1. I allow them to be chosen **more than once** (e.g. allow `{1,1}`).

   (A subset means every element is chosen once or less)
2. Also I **neglect the order** (e.g. `{1,2}` is the same as `{2,1}`).

   (In other word, I need either `{1,2}` or `{2,1}`, not both.)

---

Let's say the set `s = {a, b}`. (whose `Length` is $n$)

- `Subsets` gives `{{}, {a}, {b}, {a, b}}`. (length: $2^n$)
- `Tuples[s, n]` gives `{{a, a}, {a, b}, {b, a}, {b, b}}`. (length: $n^n$)
- `Permutations` gives `{{a, b}, {b, a}}`. (length: $n!$)
- What I want is `{{}, {a}, {b}, {a,a}, {a,b}, {b,b}}`.

  There's no `{b,a}`. (Besides, it's OK to generate `{b,a}` instead of `{a,b}`)

  (length: I can't work out the exact formula now, but I guess it's between $2^n$ and $n^n$)

---

I didn't find anything identical, but I know that I can make `Tuples` from $0$ to $n$, then `DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]`. However it's kind of silly, as most of the tuples will be deleted.

> Full code: `Table[Tuples[s, i], {i, 0, n}] // Flatten[#, 1] & // DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]`

Is there a neat way to do that?

Comment: Try: Flatten[Tuples[{a, b}, #] & /@ Range[0, 2], 1]

Comment: @DanielHuber Thanks, but it generates more than I want: either {a, b} or {b, a}, not both. (I now split the goal into an ordered list to emphasize that.)

Comment: Well with an addition we may also deal with this, but it is getting a bit cryptical: `Union[Sort /@ Flatten[Tuples[{a, b}, #] & /@ Range[0, 2], 1]]`

Comment: @DenialHuber This is similar to the  “Full code” in the question. There I use `Table` instead of `Range`, `x // f` instead of `f[x]`.

Comment: Related: [equivalent-nested-loop-structure](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35560/equivalent-nested-loop-structure-combinations-with-replacement),  [fastest-way-to-generate-a-a-a](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/268651/fastest-way-to-generate-a-a-a-b-a-c-b-b-b-c-c-c-from-a-b-c)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want an increasing sequence.
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/235768/72111

That is, for
$$1\leq a_1 \leq a_2\leq \cdots \leq a_{n}\leq m$$

We set
$$b_k=a_k+k$$
then
$$2\leq b_1< b_2<\cdots<b_n\leq m+n$$
It means that $(b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_n)$ is the $n$ subsets of `Range[2,m+n]`

```
m = 5;
n = 3;
list = Subsets[Range[2, m + n], {n}]
result = Subtract[#, Range[n]] & /@ list
{a,b,c,d,e}[[#]] & /@ result
```

> `{{a, a, a}, {a, a, b}, {a, a, c}, {a, a, d}, {a, a, e}, {a, b, b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, d}, {a, b, e}, {a, c, c}, {a, c, d}, {a, c, e}, {a,  d, d}, {a, d, e}, {a, e, e}, {b, b, b}, {b, b, c}, {b, b, d}, {b, b, e}, {b, c, c}, {b, c, d}, {b, c, e}, {b, d, d}, {b, d, e}, {b, e,  e}, {c, c, c}, {c, c, d}, {c, c, e}, {c, d, d}, {c, d, e}, {c, e,  e}, {d, d, d}, {d, d, e}, {d, e, e}, {e, e, e}}`

Comment: Save me! My problem is even simpler than it. (n == m)

Comment: `Sum[Binomial[m + n - 1, n], {n, 0, m}] // FullSimplify`

Answer (score 4):

I will use the answer by @cvgmt to get a handle on the number of elements in the list of "subsets".

Setting `m == n` and ignoring the alphabetical symbols, here are the lengths for the $n = 0, \ldots, 12$:

```
Length /@
  Table[
    Table[
      Subtract[#, Range[i]] & /@ Subsets[Range[2, 2 i], {i}],
      {i, 0, n}
    ] // Flatten[#, 1] &,
    {n, 0, 12}
  ]

(* {1, 2, 5, 15, 50, 176, 638, 2354, 8789, 33099, 125477, 478193, 1830271} *)
```

This sequence is identified as A024718 by Sequence Machine at [sequencedb.net](http://sequencedb.net). The associated formula for the $n$-th term is

```
(1/2)*(1 + Sum[Binomial[2*k, k], {k, 0, n}])

(* 1/2 (1 - I/Sqrt[3] - 
   Binomial[2 (1 + n), 1 + n] * Hypergeometric2F1[1, 3/2 + n, 2 + n, 4]) *)
```

Comment: I can't access the sequencedb.net with HTTP**S**. Is it HTTP? ([same sequence on OEIS](https://oeis.org/A024718))

Comment: @Y.D.X. You are correct. I fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
ascendingPositions = Position[Nest[Range, Range @ #, # - 1], _,  Heads -> False] &;

subsetsWithDupes = Extract[#, Map[List] @ ascendingPositions @ Length @ #] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
subsetsWithDupes[{a, b}]
```

> ```
>  {{a, a}, {a}, {b, a}, {b, b}, {b}, {}}
> ```

```
subsetsWithDupes[{a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> {{a, a, a}, {a, a}, {a}, {b, a, a}, {b, a}, {b, b, a}, {b, b, b},
>  {b, b}, {b}, {c, a, a}, {c, a}, {c, b, a}, {c, b, b}, {c, b},
>  {c, c, a}, {c, c, b}, {c, c, c}, {c, c}, {c}, {}}
> ```

```
subsetsWithDupes[{a, b, c, d}]
```

[image]

```
Count[Nest[Range, Range@#, # - 1], _, All] & /@ Range[12]
```

> ```
> {2, 6, 20, 70, 252, 924, 3432, 12870, 48620, 184756, 705432, 2704156}
> ```

```
FindSequenceFunction[%, n]
```

> ```
>  Binomial[2 n, n]
> ```

Comment: Great idea. Could you explain `Position[#, _, Heads -> False]&` in `ascendingPositions`? I can even work out its result step by step, but I have no idea what it really does.

Comment: @Y.D.X.,  [Position >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html): _With the default option setting_ Heads->True, Position _includes heads of expressions and their parts._  [Heads >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Heads.html): Heads->False _never includes heads as part of any level of an expression._