# How can I get a list of all distinct unordered pairs of numbers in a specific range?

Tags: functional-style, list-manipulation

If I do e.g.

```
Flatten[Outer[List, Range[3], Range[3]], 1]
```

I get

```
{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, 
 {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, 
 {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}}
```

but I want to get *distinct* pairs, i.e.

```
{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, 
 {2, 2}, {2, 3}, 
 {3, 3}}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/265431/is-there-a-function-to-generate-subsets-allowing-duplicates/265435#265435

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit: many thanks to @JasonB. for the comment. It has been incorporated below**

You first command can be written more simply as:

```
Tuples[Range@3, 2]
```

You can check their equivalence either by using [`SameQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ.html)

```
SameQ[Tuples[Range@3, 2], Flatten[Outer[List, Range[3], Range[3]], 1]]
```

or the undocumented function

```
LinearAlgebra`Private`ZeroArrayQ[
 Tuples[Range@3, 2] - Flatten[Outer[List, Range[3], Range[3]], 1]]
```

both of which yield

> [image: true]

To delete the values you don't want to see

```
Tuples[Range@3, 2] // DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]
```

And we check against the result you quoted in two ways. One is

```
SameQ[(Tuples[Range@3, 2] // 
    DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]) - {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {2, 
    3}, {3, 3}}]
```

and the other

```
LinearAlgebra`Private`ZeroArrayQ[(Tuples[Range@3, 2] // 
    DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]) - {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {2, 
    3}, {3, 3}}]
```

both of which yield

> [image: true]

Comment: The answer is correct - you could show that without using some undocumented private context function.  For instance you could use `SameQ`, as in `SameQ[Tuples[Range@3, 2], Flatten[Outer[List, Range[3], Range[3]], 1]]`

Comment: @JasonB. point taken and the answer is updated. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

```
n = 3;
t = Tuples[Range[1, n], {2}] /. {a_, b_} /; a > b -> Nothing
```

> {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}}

Answer (score 3):

Here are some other ways:

```
Union[Sort /@ Tuples[Range[3], 2]]

DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ Tuples[Range[3], 2]]

Union[Tuples[Range[3], 2], 
 SameTest -> ({#1[[1]], #1[[2]]} == {#2[[2]], #2[[1]]} &)]

DeleteDuplicates[
 Tuples[Range[3], 2], ({#1[[1]], #1[[2]]} == {#2[[2]], #2[[1]]} &)]
```

All yield:

> {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}}

Answer (score 3):

```
Join @@ Table[{i, j}, {i, 3}, {j, i, 3}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}}
> ```

```
Distribute[{Range@3, Range@3}, List, List, DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]@*List]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

The `Subsets` command is for this:

```
Subsets[Range[3], {1, 2}] /. {{x_} :> {x, x}}
```